# Is it possible to create one raster elevation layer from two different point layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have two layers with X,Y,Z data. The data overlay only partly.

Is it possible to create one raster layer with elevation data using the 2 sets of data but without merging them first?

Comment: Why don't you want to merge them?

Comment: Are your points from non-overlapping areas like from different map sheets?

Comment: SS_Rebelious, because I'm lazy? I was just hoping I can skip this step.

Comment: user30184, yes, the data sets overlap only partly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem description is not clear: do you want to create a vector grid or do you want to create an elevation raster from the input points?

Comment: So @underdark did not answer to your question. When it comes to your problem, you could create grid_1 with elevations from layer_1 and grid_2 from layer_2 and combine them later. However, there could be odd results at the seam because of interpolation. I would study if your shapefiles could be combined virtually with GDAL Virtual format http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html. If you will do the job only once and if you are only lazy you will just merge the shapes and go on. But I guess that you are also curious and you can work hard and waste your time for finding an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

You can press **Zoom full** to to align the map canvas with all (in your case both) input layers. Then, in the **Vector grid** tool, use the **Update extents from canvas** button to use the full extent which you just zoomed to.

Comment: Perhaps user means a grid with attributes like the ones created with http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html?

Comment: underdark, but where do I assign the values (elevation data) for the grid?.